# Get only certain amount of children from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app I am using this code to retrieve posts from firebase database:

```
ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot){
                   String author = dsp.child("author").getValue().toString();
                   String text = dsp.child("author").getValue().toString();
                    posts.add(new Post(author,text));
            }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

But this returns all the posts and if there would be many of them I think it wouldn't be good idea to keep them all in memory. Is there a way to get only certain number of node's children? For example at the beginning I would like to get 10 first ones, then 10 more and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `limitToFirst()` (or `limitToLast()`).

```
ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = dbRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(10);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot){
               String author = dsp.child("author").getValue().toString();
               String text = dsp.child("author").getValue().toString();
                posts.add(new Post(author,text));
        }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

See the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for an explanation of all its capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your DataSnapShot to retrieve more specific information.

There is a Firebase guide for Android that explain how to utilize: [Firebase Android Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#childeventlistener_onChildAdded)

If you would prefer to see on Stack OverFlow a small example this answer here seems to be doing somewhat of what you would like to achieve: [Firebase Get Children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27188987/4518455)