# Firebase Data Structure - Users

Tags: firebase

We are trying to create a simple chat application using Firebase as the backend.
We are struggling with the right data structure to use.

So we have **rooms** and **users**. It's a many to many relation: one **room** can have many **users** as members and one **user** can be a member of many **rooms**. How do we structure this data?

If we do the following:

```
room {
  name: ,
  desc: ,
  members: [
    users {
     name: ,
     email: ,
     age: ,
     bio: ,
     ...
    }
  ]
}
```

How do we update the **user** details when that changes? And if we did the opposite, of having **rooms** a property of the **users** node, how do we update the **rooms**? I considered having another object **relations** with a pointer to **room** and a pointer to **member**, but I didn't find a way to use pointers in Firebase.

```
relations {
  user: <pointer to users>
  room: <pointer to rooms>
}
```

Any advice would be helpful. I have looked at various articles including Anant's [Denormalizing you Database is normal](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), but haven't been able to solve our case.

Comment: I've described a few possible approaches of fanning out data changes in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase/30699277#30699277. My original answer on data structuring is probably also a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638660/firebase-data-structure-and-url/16651115#16651115

Comment: Although not completely, it helps me find a workaround for my problem. So thank you. Great answers on the other two questions btw!

Comment: Great examples [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-revisiting-advanced-example) and [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-login-demo) in the docs, including live code. Also chat apps listed in the [examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/examples.html)