# Firebase orderByChild() with nested keys

Tags: firebase

Firebase orderByChild() works well when child properties have names, so that with data like this:

```
groups
    <groupID>
        groupStatus: "Active"
```

is is easy to get the groupIDs of the groups with "Active" status by this:

```
var ref = "http://myFirebase.firebaseio.com/groups";
ref.orderByChild("groupStatus").equalTo("Active").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

But I have firebase data of groups and the members of those groups in the following form:

```
groups
    group123
        member404: true
        member503: true
        ...
    group124
        member503: true
        member221: true
        ...
```

I need to generate a list of all the memberIDs who are "friends" of a particular member, defined as being in at least one group in common with them.  For member 503, you would think this would be a orderByChild() opportunity. But since the memberIDs are keys nested under the groups, what would the syntax be?

Something like:

```
ref.orderByChild(???).equalTo("member503")
```

Of course, I could get all the members of all the groups into an array locally, but surely there is a way to get firebase to do this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up child keys and values here. The solution:

```
ref.child('groups').orderByChild('member404').equalTo(true)
```

Comment: Yes, `membersRef.orderByChild(uid).equalTo(true)` works for the query, but now my problem is how to create an index to make it perform.  Firebase complains "Consider adding ".indexOn": "41ab3832-6a90-4141-bdf5-92c5cac0f99c" which is a specific member ID.  Obviously, that's not practical.  And it's not possible to use $location variable in index specification.  Anyone know how to index this correctly?

Comment: Yup. You'd do that by creating your own so-called *reverse index*. In your list of users, also keep track of the groups they're a member of. That way you can do a direct look-up of "groups for user" and of "users for group". In a NoSQL world, direct look-up will always trump querying for the same data. Have a read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638660/firebase-data-structure-and-url/16651115#16651115