# Firebase Data Retrieval, Path Inside Path

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know if it possible to access another path while within the completion block of a current path.

The way I am using it is as follows... I have a social media app, with a "Posts" path. That obviously is where I get all my information for the Posts. I would like to create "Comment(s)" for each post. That is where I would like there to be a  path to "Comment(s)."  What is someones recommendation for achieving this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend first reading my classic answer on a similar question: [Firebase data structure and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638660/firebase-data-structure-and-url/16651115#16651115)

Nesting data is in general discouraged in the Firebase Database. There have various reasons for that, but a few:

- you can only retrieve a complete node. So if you nest the comments under each post, it means you will automatically get all comments whenever you are getting a post.
- you often want different access rules on each of these types (posts vs comments). This is more difficult to manage when you nest them, since permission trickles down.

I would have three top-level lists: `posts` and `comments`.

```
posts
    $postid
        author: "uidOfCoderCody"
        title: "Firebase Data Retrieval, Path Inside Path" 
        body: "I would like to know if it possible to..."
comments
    $postid
        $commentid
            author: "uidOfZassX"
            comment: "Here is sample code of how it should work."
```

Since the comments are stored under the same `$postid` of the post itself, you can easily look up the comments for a post.

Depending on the use-cases that your app covers, you'll need to adapt or (more likely) expand this data model to efficiently allow your use-cases. For learning more, I also recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: I like your strategy better. I'm guessing I can access the autoID of a post using dot notation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can definitely get the autoID/key of the posts. After you call `let newPostRef = ref.childByAutoId()`, you can get it by `newPostRef.key`.

Comment: @CoderCody my answer below is how to read from Firebase if structure is like this one above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code of how it should work. Using the same method in my projects. Of course, path is fake so fill it with your actual path.

```
// Read all posts from Firebase
ref.child("posts").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            // Loop through all posts
            for snap in snapshots {

                // Read comments for each post. snap.key in code below represents post key. Don't know if you have same structure so fill your data here.
                ref.child("comment").child(snap.key).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    if let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        // Here you have comments for current post

                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: As soon as I am able to accept it I will. Thank you for your help!