# Firebase Firestore - get additional data for each document on collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have this list of messages objects, with a message, a user_id and a date. I actually want to retrieve user informations together with each message.

```
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.afs.collection('/messages").snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(snapshots => {
      resolve(snapshots)
    })
})
```

I don't think iterating on the messages to get users is what I want to do - there should be a much better way. I'm also not sure about the recommandations I read at some places about storing the whole user data for each location where you could need it... I don't like it.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: If you are interested, here you can find the [database schema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo&t=176s&index=3&list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb) for a chat app in which you have all user details in every place are needed.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here by Frank from Firebase [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638660/firebase-data-structure-and-url/16651115#16651115) in relation to the Realtime Database. This will most likely be applicable to your use case as well. There is also a great little support document listing out the advantages of the different approaches with Firestore [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data).

Depending on your specific use case, it might or might not be tenable to store user data in your message object. You might have heard of data duplication and de-normalisation  which is a common practice in NoSQL databases.

Without knowing too much about your use case, I would store user_id's on the message object and fetch them if and when they are needed.

Comment: As I said, that's what I did; I store the user_id on the message object. And thank you for the link, it's nice to refresh a little about how to structure data ! The question, though, is about the possibility to fetch user's data from USERS node directly when fetching the message that have a user_id, instead of waiting for the response and then get each user's info through a loop.