# Beginner Firebase in JS: Getting the subsequent k items

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a Firebase database with News items, in which we will always be displaying 10 articles at a time in our front page. We want to have these articles sorted by time, so all we have been doing is pushing into our firebase ref like so:

```
myDataRef.child("News/").push(json);
```

What we want to do now is have functionality in which if a user clicks the next button, the 10 subsequent articles are loaded from the database. I thought about doing this by increasing a variable called page which correctly holds the current page number.

The issue arises when it comes to the query itself. Since is seems that snapshot.val() is always null.

```
        myDataRef.child("News").startAt(page*10).endAt(page*10+10).once('value',function(snapshot){
             console.log(snapshot.val())
        });
```

even if I change the query to be a hard coded:

```
 myDataRef.child("News").startAt(0).endAt(10).once('value',function(snapshot){
            console.log(snapshot.val())
 });
```

It still logs a null. I am sure the "News" db has at least 50 entries in it. So I am confident the mistakes are at the query.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See this question and answer for how this used to work a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628362/pagination-in-application-which-use-firebase-com-as-database. Even with the new `orderBy...` methods the operation remains fairly similar: you remember the last item that you showed and start from that for the next page. If you've used "continuously increasing but not necessarily sequential" keys (such as the ones Firebase generates when you call `push`) this will work perfectly: `startAt` will return the next key if the current one was deleted in that case.

Comment: Reading [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) and sponging up all those fundamentals would be a great primer for understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to order your data before using helper methods such as `startAt` & `endAt`. This is because `startAt` looks for matches on certain properties, not specific indexes. Even if you have some date or timestamp property on your articles, and try `orderByChild('time')` you couldn't really chain `.startAt(page * 10)` because it would look for a match on the time property, which may or may not be an integer.

What you can do to get around this is have some `totalArticles` variable that gets updated whenever you store a new article. Then if you add an `articleNumber` property to each article that corresponds to whatever `totalArticles` was at the time of saving, you can then `orderByChild('articleNumber').startAt(page * 10).endAt(page * 10 + 10)`

Alternatively, it seems like a second parameter to `startAt` can be the key or index

see more here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html
and https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

edit:
check out this awesome post on firebase blog which explains this problem in detail, courtesy of @FrankvanPuffelen:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: That seems like a good workaround, yet what happens if I delete articles?

Comment: In a dynamic, realtime database such as Firebase, you should not depend on keys that are perfectly sequential. Those become a bottleneck when multiple users end up adding items at the same time. Firebase's `push` method generates keys that are ideally suited for array-like use-cases and they'll work with `startAt` and `endAt` perfectly. Also see this article for an example: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#paginate. Keep in mind that it also pre-dates the `orderBy...` methods, so you now have more (but similar) options.

Comment: This article by Kato gives a better explanation of Firebase's reasoning when it comes to arrays: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen! I am currently using the resources you showed for pagination and its working pretty well! I'll keep you updated

Comment: That article is outdated. [See here for a more modern read](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase) of the same material.